# Sending strings as parameter to bash script to automate Git commands using Git Alias

Tags: bash, git, shell

I have a bash script that I've been using for a while to automate the following Git commands into a single command for ease-of-use:

```
git add.
git commit -m
git push
```

The script is defined in the .gitconfig file as an alias. It's worked really well so far, but I'd like to be able to add some extra functionality to it so that I can pass in two strings instead of one. The first string will be a JIRA ticket number, while the second is the commit message. The ticker number will be prepended to the commit message before the commit is pushed to remote.

I've tried altering my script but now when I enter the three parameters I get a `too many arguments` error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong though.

```
!f() 
{ 
    ticketNumber=$1 
    commitmessage=$2
    confirm=$3; 

    if [ $2 = 1 ]; 
    then 
    git add .; 
    git status; 
    git commit -m \"[${ticketNumber}] ${commitmessage}\"; 
    git push; fi 
    }; 
f
```

For example the following function call produces the error:

`git commitpushthis "JIRA-137" "Test commit message" 1`

Comment: The idea is a bit clear but your post is quite confusing. In the beginning you state that you want to pass in 2 strings instead of one. Your example shows no variables being used nor an original script. The next part says that you get an error when you pass 3 arguments. Didn't you want to pass only 2 arguments?

Comment: Where are you defining `f`? The `!` is invalid shell syntax; its use in defining a Git alias is to instruct Git to treat what follows as a shell command, not another Git subcommand.

Comment: You have an additional error `[$2 = 1]`. Isn't `$2` the commit message? Don't you wan't to check `$3`?

Comment: The backslashes in the call to `git commit` are also suspect, depending on where you are actually defining `f`.

Comment: @RedX Sorry, I'll be clearer. I want to pass in 2 strings and 1 integer as parameters, the strings are to be concatenated to produce the commit message. The integer is just a check, it's not really needed. Yes, you're correct about the `[$2 = 1]` being incorrect.

Comment: @chepner `f` is being defined in `.gitconfig` under an alias. The full alias is as follows `commitpushthis = "!f() { ... }`

Comment: Then you should put that in the question.

Comment: @chepner Updated the original question and provided an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$2` is unquoted, meaning you end up with a command like

```
[ Test commit message = 1 ]
```

Quoting `$2` would fix that, although only long enough for you to realize you mean to use `$3` anyway. The correct definition would appear to be (with variable names omitted for conciseness):

```
commitpushthis = "!f() { if [ \"$3\" = 1 ]; then git add .; git status; git commit -m \"[${ticketNumber}] ${commitmessage}\"; git push; fi; }; f"
```

Comment: This is the code I ended up with as well, thanks. I'll mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fit the problem. Apparently it was being caused by the incorrect `if [$2 = 1] as another user pointed out.

The new code shown below works as intended.

```
!f() 
{ 
    ticketNumber=$1 
    commitmessage=$2
    confirm=$3; 

    if [ $3 = 1 ]; 
    then 
    git add .; 
    git status; 
    git commit -m \"[${ticketNumber}] ${commitmessage}\"; 
    git push; fi 
    }; 
f
```

Comment: `$3` should be quoted as well. Just because you *expect* the argument to be 1 (or at least a single word) doesn't mean it *will* be when the alias gets used. You'd also get an error if you omit the third argument altogether, assuming that an empty argument is the same as "argument that isn't 1".